# Not able to login to the website through my VBA code

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have made the below mentioned code for logging in to the website https://www.tdscpc.gov.in/app/login.xhtml

The code is filling up the values on the website tabs just fine, but when I click the login button it does not recognizes the values and gives error to fill up the values again.

I have attached images of the website showing the state:

**a).after running the code but before clicking login button.**

1. [image: after running the code but before clicking login button.]

**b). and after clicking login button.**

2. [image: and after clicking login button.]

I'm not able to figure out why this is happening and what is wrong in my code.

```
Sub Login_Traces()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.tdscpc.gov.in/app/login.xhtml"
Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set DOC = IE.document

DOC.getElementById("userId").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Traces ID & Password").Range("b3").Value

DOC.getElementById("psw").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Traces ID & Password").Range("c3").Value

DOC.getElementById("tanpan").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Traces ID & Password").Range("d3").Value


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to test your code on my side but I did not get the same error as yours.

I try to check the source of that page and there is an **Onchange** event on Username and Password field.

You can try to fire the **change** event after setting the value in the field that may help to fix the issue. The function on the OnChnage event is displaying the captcha code.

Sample code to fire the change event:

```
Set ieEvent = htmldoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
ieEvent.initEvent "change", False, True
ie.document.all.Item("txt1").dispatchEvent ieEvent
```

Modified code:

```
Sub Login_Traces()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://nriservices.tdscpc.gov.in/nriapp/login.xhtml"
Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set DOC = IE.document

Set ieEvent = DOC.createEvent("HTMLEvents")

ieEvent.initEvent "change", False, True

DOC.getElementById("userId").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

IE.document.all.Item("userId").dispatchEvent ieEvent

DOC.getElementById("psw").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

IE.document.all.Item("psw").dispatchEvent ieEvent

DOC.getElementById("tanpan").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value


End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

You can see that now it is showing that User Id is not as per specified format because we are entering the dummy user id. you can enter the correct id will fix this error.